# Undoing tensor dstack and restack column-wise

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have two, tensors, `a` and `b`:

```py
import torch

a = torch.tensor(([1,2],
                  [3,4],
                  [5,6],
                  [7,8]))

b = torch.tensor(([0,0],
                  [1,1],
                  [2,2],
                  [3,3]))
```

Which I can stack both horizontally or depth-wise.

```py
d = torch.dstack([a, b])
h = torch.hstack([a, b])
```

Now, is there any PyTorch function, preferably in one line, that I can apply to `d` to get `h`? It sounds like I want to undo the depth-wise stacking, and re-stack them column-wise. I've tried reshaping, and flattening, but neither work, as they both disrupt the ordering of the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case use `torch.unbind`

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor(([1,2],
                  [3,4],
                  [5,6],
                  [7,8]))

b = torch.tensor(([0,0],
                  [1,1],
                  [2,2],
                  [3,3]))

d = torch.dstack([a, b])
h = torch.hstack(torch.unbind(d,2)) # get h from d
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I went through all the documentation but I would never have imagined that it went by `unbind`.